# How can I fix this error : getting error in action cable rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I write below code in `game.coffe` this file

```
App.game = App.cable.subscriptions.create "GameChannel",
  connected: ->
   ...

  disconnected: ->
   ...
  received: (data) ->
    switch data.action
      when "game_start"
        $('#status').html("Player found")
        App.gamePlay = new Game('#game-container', data.msg)

      when "take_turn"
        App.gamePlay.move data.move
        App.gamePlay.getTurn()

      when "new_game"
        App.gamePlay.newGame()

      when "opponent_withdraw"
        $('#status').html("Opponent withdraw, You win!")
        $('#new-match').removeClass('hidden');

  take_turn: (move) ->
    @perform 'take_turn', data: move

  new_game: () ->
    @perform 'new_game'
```

when i run this code in browser it will show me erro like this

```
game.self-9aed049….js?body=1:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: Game is not defined
```

in browser's console.

Comment: Where is `Game` supposed to come from? How did you arrange for `Game` to be global?

Comment: @muistooshort i did this from http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/tic-tac-toe-game-in-rails-5-with-action-cable/ but i am geting error

Comment: The code in the blog post is incomplete, apparently you need to grab the whole thing from Github.

Comment: @muistooshort I did this from Github. still iam getting error.